# how to covert Y,U,V buffer to one-dimensional array

Tags: c++, yuv, openh264

I'm trying to convert an hls file to jpeg. firstly, I used [openh264](https://github.com/cisco/openh264/wiki/UsageExampleForDecoder) to convert HLS file to YUV. I got a two dimensional array containing Y, U, V buffer (*pData[3]). After that, I try to combine the three arrays into one to pass it to [CompressYUYV2JPEG](https://gist.github.com/royshil/fa98604b01787172b270). 
here is how I convert:

```
for(i = 0; i < l; i++) {
        inbuf.push_back(yuvData[0][i]);
    }
    l = bufferInfo.UsrData.sSystemBuffer.iWidth*bufferInfo.UsrData.sSystemBuffer.iHeight/4;
    for(i = 0; i < l; i++) {
        inbuf.push_back(yuvData[1][i]);
    }
    l = bufferInfo.UsrData.sSystemBuffer.iWidth*bufferInfo.UsrData.sSystemBuffer.iHeight/4;
    for(i = 0; i < l; i++) {
        inbuf.push_back(yuvData[2][i]);
    }
```

but unfortunately, It doesn't produce the expected result. What is the proper way to convert 2-dimensional YUV array into a one-dimensional array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need YUV422. That means YUYV. `inbuf` must be dividable by 4 for every input data. You can use

```
for(i = 0; i < l/2; i++) {
    inbuf.push_back(yuvData[0][2*i]);
    inbuf.push_back((yuvData[1][2*i] + yuvData[1][2*i + 1])/2);
    inbuf.push_back(yuvData[0][2*i + 1]);
    inbuf.push_back((yuvData[2][2*i] + yuvData[2][2*i + 1])/2);
}
```

In this code snippet all Y values are used but only the average of two Cr resp. Cb values are used. Of course the number of elements in each yuvData channel must be even. Otherwise you have to find a solution for the last element.

I just now saw that you use YUV420. Then you can use this snippet

```
for(i = 0; i < l/2; i++) {
    inbuf.push_back(yuvData[0][2*i]);
    inbuf.push_back(yuvData[1][i/2]);
    inbuf.push_back(yuvData[0][2*i + 1]);
    inbuf.push_back(yuvData[2][i/2]);
}
```

In this code all Y values are used once and all Cr resp. Cb values are used twice.

Comment: isn't YUV422 "YUYV-YUYV..."? but your code uses "YYUV-YYUV"? did you just make a mistake?

Comment: ref: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YUV#Y%E2%80%B2UV422_to_RGB888_conversion

Comment: The comment in your link says "Each four bytes is two Y's, a Cb and a Cr." But in the code it is YUYV. You are right. I fixed it

Comment: btw, how do I calculate 'l'? for(i = 0; i < l/2; i++)

Comment: @Pittie It's the same `l` you had in your code snippet. `l` is the number of pixels `bufferInfo.UsrData.sSystemBuffer.iWidth*bufferInfo.UsrData.sSystemBuffer.iHeight`